# Game Over Scene doesn't work (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity C# and I want to make a Game Over scene.

I created a C# script (`GameOverScript`):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameOverScript : MonoBehaviour {

int score = 0;

void Start () {


    score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");

}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 40, 50, 80, 30), "GAME OVER");
    GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 40, 300, 80, 30), "Score: " + score);
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 30, 350, 60, 30), "Retry?"));
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(0);
    }
}

}
```

It works, but it just shows for about 2 seconds and the game restarts automatically. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Try to add Console.Log("{{some text}}") after Application.LoadLevel(0); and check, maybe it calls, when you nowexpect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please delete ; (located after if condition)

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 40, 300, 80, 30), "Score: " + score);
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 30, 350, 60, 30), "Retry?")) //---->;
{
    Application.LoadLevel(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the IEnumerator function? The way I tend to delay is using `WaitForSeconds()`. For Example,

```
IEnumerator PauseFunc(){

yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); //5 second pause

}
```

Then back up in your code above you'd want to start a CoRoutine. StartCoroutine("PauseFunc");